# How do I call a method on a WebBrowser inside an event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, events, webbrowser-control

This is what I have:

```
public void initiate(WebBrowser browser)
{         
   browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(refDocumentCompleted);
   // navigate browser to the referal Uri
   browser.Navigate(refreral);

   browser.DocumentCompleted -= refDocumentCompleted;
   //remove here so that it doesn't do this everytime a document is completed, i want it just in this method
}

private void refDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // want to call navigate method on browser here. but Its out of scope.
}
```

What I would like it to do is, navigating to `referral`, then once that is loaded navigate to another page stored as a global string in the class.

I'm sure my trouble here is from a poor understanding of how events work, I've tried to read up on it, but can't seem to get my head around it but don't think I need to create my own handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the webbrowser object. You just need to cast it:

```
((WebBrowser)sender).Navigate(...);
```

etc.

Comment: The casting, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Use lambdas, e.g.:

```
public void initiate(WebBrowser browser)
{

    browser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) => {
        browser.DoStuff(); // it's in scope via closure
    };

    // etc
}
```

EDIT: to add / remove it, assign the lambda to a variable:

```
public void initiate(WebBrowser browser)
{

    var doStuff = (sender, e) => {
        browser.DoStuff(); // it's in scope via closure
    };

    browser.DocumentCompleted += doStuff;

    // etc

    browser.DocumentCompleted -= doStuff;
}
```

Comment: That's how I had it initially but, how would I remove it then?

Comment: Create the closure as a variable, then add & remove it.  Answer changed.

Answer (score 0):

In your `initiate` method store the `WebBrowser` in an instance field, then reference it from your event handler:

```
private WebBrowser _browser;

// inside initiate 
_browser = browser;

// Inside event handler
_browser.Navigate(...);
```

Comment: Well, you *could* avoid the event handler method and use a lambda expression instead - this will give you access to the browser instance. I don't think it's cleaner, though.

Comment: Well I suppose this alloud me to do what I asked, but it still doesn't do what I wanted because it is removing the handler before the event happens.